# Checking if a value in the state is changed in class components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The project is already started using class-based React and I can't switch to hooks.
So I basically have a form, which could either be edited (there is data coming from the server that is supposed to fill the form with the last data it was filled with) or start a new one(which is empty, I don't need help with that).

I have a variable in the state which checks for that: isEdit - checks if the form is being edited, or it's an empty start, a variable in the state called loadedCategories which is a number array and is being filled with categories ids from the last time the form was edited/created only isEdited is true.

On the other hand, we have another var in the state: currentLoadedCategories, which is again a number array and is being filled only when there is a change made to the input field called Categories.

Now the main issue is that I want when currentLoadedCategories is being changed, which will happen when the input is being changed, I want to empty currendLoadedCategories.

I will give you an example with hooks since it's my strong side and I need your help to implement it with classes.

```
useEffect(() => {
if(isEdit){
setloadedCategories([]) 
}
}, [currentLoadedCategories])
```

Simply said all I want is to detect when something is being changed in the state, just like the example.

Comment: Official docs are a great resource, you want [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate).

Answer (score 0):

The method `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)` would be useful here, you juste have to compare `prevState` with `this.state` to see what changed !